# TimescaleDB timestamp types

Tags: postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

I have been using TimescaleDB for quite some time now and I was just wondering what the data types are for the timeseries data that it supports.
More specifically, I was wondering if UNIX timestamps are supported as time series data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hypertable/create_hypertable/#returns -> units section a little further down

> The 'time' column supports the following data types:
> Timestamp (TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMPTZ),
> DATE,
> Integer (SMALLINT, INT, BIGINT)

Comment: Considering that unix timestamps are long int's. I am assuming TimescaleDB supports unix timestamps.